# Resolve a word &quota in PHP?

Tags: php, json, cpanel

I found a very strange bug using this word "&quota".

I am using the cPanel API.

I tested Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and others.

Do it yourself.

Simple PHP:

```
<?php 
    echo "&quota";
?>
```

Return:

```
"a
```

JSON API shape cPanel

https://hostname.example.com:2087/cpsess##########/json-api/cpanel?cpanel_jsonapi_user=user&cpanel_jsonapi_apiversion=2&cpanel_jsonapi_module=Email&cpanel_jsonapi_func=addpop&domain="example.com"&email="user"&password="12345luggage"&quota="500"

Return:

https://hostname.example.com:2087/cpsess##########/json-api/cpanel?cpanel_jsonapi_user=user&cpanel_jsonapi_apiversion=2&cpanel_jsonapi_module=Email&cpanel_jsonapi_func=addpop&domain="example.com"&email="user"&password="12345luggage""a="500"

Could someone help me put this "&quota"?

I tried to think of everything.

I already put:

Is it possible to cheat using PHP?

"a -> back &quota

&QUOTA

Believe appears and &quoTA, but does not send the string (should be lowercase).

Comment: `&quot` is the html entitie for `'` you should be using http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: @IdontDownVote Interesting could you explain me an example to revert

Comment: @IdontDownVote I did so echo urlencode("&quota"); %26quota It is?

Comment: Did you try &&quota="50"? Double ampersand instead of one

Comment: did you see the manual page note "Note:

Be careful about variables that may match HTML entities. Things like &amp, &copy and &pound are parsed by the browser and the actual entity is used instead of the desired variable name. This is an obvious hassle that the W3C has been telling people about for years." thats exactly your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching on http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2. and in the PHP manual using urldecode and urlencode for help  "@IdontDownVote"  I understood better about my problem.

What did I do

```
<?php
$e_com=htmlentities(urldecode('&quota=1000'));
echo $e_com;
?>
```

I had to decode
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urldecode.php

Thank you very much